# MIME type warning when plotting data with R in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, mime-types, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I can't figure this one out. Every time I plot data with R (IRKernel) into a Jupyter notebook I get a warning message that says "No renderer could be found for output. It has the following MIME types:" I'm using Chrome to display my notebooks using Jupyter Lab.

Thing is, the plots are perfectly displayed, so I don't quite understand why I'm getting this message. I tried changing the MIME type to png and svg+xml in the corresponding cells, but I keep getting the warning we both.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The topic is actively being discussed on the [IRkernel issue page](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/597). For me, adding a `print()` function around the ggplot command made the message disappear, but that is not much of a solution to the underlying problem!